# How can I get inner join of two graphs in Apache Jena with SPARQL without UNION/FILTER?

Tags: nested, sparql, jena, named-graphs

I have an Apache Jena based ontology and I have two named graphs in it:

***m_p***

```
p1    pred1    mp1
p2    pred1    mp1
p3    pred1    mp2
p4    pred1    mp2
p5    pred1    mp3
p6    pred1    mp3
```

and ***m_p_s***

```
mp1   pred2    w:frnd
mp1   pred2    w:fdlfkdl
mp2   pred2    w:kdsjflk
mp2   pred2    w:jflksdlkj
mp3   pred2    w:frnd
mp3   pred2    w:fjksldjfls
```

and I want to get all the triples in ***m_p***, which objects are predicates in ***m_p_s*** and the object of that predicates in ***m_p_s*** is **w:frnd**

In other words I want to make query that returns (results with) **p1**, **p2**, **p5** and **p6** from ***m_p*** and doesn’t return **p3** and **p4**.

I’m trying to do this with nested queries, but it doesn’t work: E.g.

```
SELECT $subj $pred $pr
FROM NAMED named_graph:m_p
WHERE
{
    SELECT $pr
    WHERE
    {
       GRAPH named_graph:m_p_s { $pr $pred0 w:frnd }
    }
}
```

returns empty result. I tried different things, but either I get an error or empty result or everything in ***m_p***.

I don’t want to use ***UNION*** or ***FILTER*** for performance reasons.

Do you have an idea how I can do it?

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Note: I've skipped the prefix declaration to shorten the post for better readability. E.g. the 'named_graph' is a prefix with URI <http://ao.com/namedGraph/>

Comment: Your outer query doesn't select any triple pattern. Where shell the bindings of `$subj` and `$pred` come from? Thus, shouldn't there be `?subj  ?pred  ?pr` before the sub-SELECT? I.e. `SELECT  ?subj ?pred ?pr
FROM NAMED named_graph:m_p
WHERE
  { ?subj  ?pred  ?pr
    { SELECT  ?pr
      WHERE
        { GRAPH named_graph:m_p_s
            { ?pr  ?pred0  w:frnd }
        }
    }
  }`   I'll test it in 2h when I'm back, maybe something also is missing regarding the graphs

Comment: Please don't shorten queries - make sure that can be cut-and-pasted so that the readers can get exactly what you use.

Answer (score 2):

The inner SELECT isn't necessary: it hides the second use of ?p but that can be done by using a different name:

```sql
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
FROM named_graph:m_p
FROM NAMED named_graph:m_p_s
{
   ?s ?p ?o
   GRAPH named_graph:m_p_s { ?o ?px w:frnd }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you mean by "I want to get all the triples in m_p, which objects are predicates in m_p_s". If you mean "whose objects are subjects in m_p_s", it would make more sense:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM named_graph:m_p
FROM NAMED named_graph:m_p_s
WHERE
{
  ?s ?p ?o
  {
     SELECT ?o WHERE {
       GRAPH named_graph:m_p_s { ?o ?p w:frnd }
      }
  }
}
```